How to improve the speed of adding documents to chromaDB?
I am trying to add chunks of text into ChromaDB. While adding the chunks, the process takes more time due to vectorization. Is there any way to speed up this process? I would like to use Celery for processing each chunk in parallel or utilize multiprocessing.
This is my sample code snippet:
ids = [str(Id) for Id in range(len(splitted_document))]
collection.add(
    ids=ids,
    documents=splitted_document
)

This line of code 'collection.add' takes more time.
I want to run the process in the background, especially as a parallel process. I tried using Celery with ChromaDB, but the documents are not being added. I checked this using collection.count(), and it returned 0. Why is this happening?
Here is the code:
# main.py 

def FileLoader(file_path):
 # Code to split the document... 
 ... 
 ... 
     
 ids = [str(Id) for Id in range(len(splitted_document))] 

 collection.add( ids=ids,
                documents=splitted_document 
              ) 

# Call the function process_file.delay(file_path)



# tasks.py  
@shared_task 
def process_file(file_path): 
 return FileLoader(file_path)

However, no documents are being added.

And this is a Django project

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
